# What is the difference between BFS and DFS algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

A timeout occurred when solving an algorithm problem with BFS. However, there is a problem that can be solved with DFS. Why does this difference occur?

The problem is to calculate the number of arrivals from (1,1) to (N, N) by moving horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

It took 1331.0ms if the problem was solved by BFS (worst case), and 62.0ms when it was solved by DFS. (I have created and tested 16 * 16 arrays.)

Attach the issue URL. (But please understand that it is Korean.)
URL> https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/17070

The answer I want to hear is...

1. I thought the BFS algorithm would be faster, but why is DFS faster?
2. Is BFS slower because there are many elements in the queue? I want to know the exact reason.

Implementation code>

class Location {

```
int x;
int y;
int dir;

public Location(int x, int y, int dir) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dir = dir;
}
```

}

public class Main {

```
static int[][] map;
static int Answer;
static int N;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st;

    N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    map = new int[N + 1][N + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {

        st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());

        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            map[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    }
    DFS(1, 2, 0);
    System.out.println(Answer);
    Answer = 0;
    BFS(1, 2, 0);
    System.out.println(Answer);
    br.close();
}

static void DFS(int x, int y, int pre) {

    if (x == N && y == N) {

        Answer++;
        return;
    }

    if (pre == 0) {

        if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0)
            DFS(x, y + 1, 0);

        if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0 && x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0 && map[x + 1][y + 1] == 0)
            DFS(x + 1, y + 1, 1);
    } else if (pre == 1) {

        if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0)
            DFS(x, y + 1, 0);

        if (x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0)
            DFS(x + 1, y, 2);

        if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0 && x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0 && map[x + 1][y + 1] == 0)
            DFS(x + 1, y + 1, 1);
    } else {

        if (x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0)
            DFS(x + 1, y, 2);

        if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0 && x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0 && map[x + 1][y + 1] == 0)
            DFS(x + 1, y + 1, 1);
    }
}

static void BFS(int startX, int startY, int dir) {

    ArrayDeque<Location> arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();
    arrayDeque.add(new Location(startX, startY, dir));

    Location location;
    int x, y, pre;

    while(!arrayDeque.isEmpty()) {

        location = arrayDeque.remove();
        x = location.x;
        y = location.y;
        pre = location.dir;

            if(x == N-1 && y == N-1) {
               Answer++; continue;
            }

        if (pre == 0) {

            if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0)
                arrayDeque.add(new Location(x, y + 1, 0));

            if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0 && x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0 && map[x + 1][y + 1] == 0)
                arrayDeque.add(new Location(x + 1, y + 1, 1));
        } else if (pre == 1) {

            if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0)
                arrayDeque.add(new Location(x, y + 1, 0));

            if (x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0)
                arrayDeque.add(new Location(x + 1, y, 2));

            if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0 && x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0 && map[x + 1][y + 1] == 0)
                arrayDeque.add(new Location(x + 1, y + 1, 1));
        } else {

            if (x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0)
                arrayDeque.add(new Location(x + 1, y, 2));

            if (y + 1 <= N && map[x][y + 1] == 0 && x + 1 <= N && map[x + 1][y] == 0 && map[x + 1][y + 1] == 0)
                arrayDeque.add(new Location(x + 1, y + 1, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Generally speaking, BFS has a consistent runtime dependent on the depth of the answer (and guaranteed to find an answer if one exists if the problem space is a tree). DFS is much more swingy (luck-based), depending on whether you pick the right branch, and can be much faster than BFS, or much slower (or even neverending, if the problem space has infinite depth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both BFS and DFS have `O(|V| + |E|)` time complexity, and the time difference you are experiencing is most probably rooted in a mistake in the implementation of the BFS which is breaking the *loop invariant*.

One of the more common mistakes made while implementing BFS is adding the same element to the queue multiple times. One should only add a vertex `v` to the queue once, so that you can ensure it's removed a single time. Unless you do so, then the asymptotic runtime (i.e. its complexity) will not be linear anymore. You can see the relevant [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) chapter for the proof of that, based on the *loop invariant* concept they introduce.

In other words, BFS is a traversal algorithm. It finds out *which* vertices are reachable, not the number of routes to reach every vertex `v`. If you try to compute the number of ways `Kv` to reach to each `v` from `(1, 1)` through BFS, the complexity becomes larger than linear. **If** the problem asks you to find `Kv`, then your approach should be to use memoization and dynamic programming, not BFS.

Specifically, based on the code you provided, your algorithm does not seem to keep track of whether a vertex (i e. a cell in the grid) was previously explored or not. This causes the vertices to be explored multiple times, which beats the point of using a graph traversal algorithm like BFS and DFS. Using the terminology I mentioned above, you are going against the loop invariant of BFS, which states that *each vertex is popped from the queue only once*. This causes the complexity of your code to go much higher than linear.

You should look into the term *memoization* and figure out a way to find a solutions for `(N, N)`, using the solutions you compute **only once** for `(N-1, N-1)`, `(N-1, N)` and `(N, N-1)`.

Comment: @Taylous I updated my answer based on the code sample you provided.

Comment: Note that in order to find the solution for (N,N) based on solutions for (N-1, N-1), (N-1, N) and (N, N-1) - or in general update the array with number of solutions for each cell - you need to split the total possible solutions into three solutions based on whether the last move was horizontal, vertical or diagonal. (Since otherwise the diagonal moves would be counted three times: diagonal, horizontal->vertical, vertical->horizontal.)

Comment: Yeah, there is a third parameter of direction involved. But I was simply meaning to hint at how memoization and DP approach works, as opposed to offering all the details of one.

Answer (score 0):

Your BFS implementation uses dynamic memory allocation and an ArrayDeque; your DFS avoids that. That will increase the cost per node for your BFS, although it is odd that it would be that much.

You could try to allocate a new Location in each call of DFS (and possibly add and remove it from an ArrayDeque) and see if that causes the same performance loss.

Additionally your BFS doesn't stop directly when x=y=N; but I don't see that it significantly increases the run-time.

Comment: I wrote the article first and erased the code. But the answerer asked for the code. So it seems to have been skipped in a hurry. Thank you for answer.